# Image not showing up in imageView

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview

In my app, I have pins on a map with rightCalloutButtons in the annotationView that pull up the second view when pressed. On the second view, the user can take a picture that is then put in the imageView. I assign the image to the image property of the mkannotation that was selected, but the image is not showing up. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?
Here is some code:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    _annotation.image = image;

    [imageView setImage:_annotation.image];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES
                             completion:nil];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [imageView setImage:_annotation.image]
}
```

Here is where the _annotation ivar is set to the mkannotation that I stored in an array:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView willDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if(buttonIndex==1)
    {
        _annotation = [[Data singleton].annotations objectAtIndex:identifier];
        [[Data singleton] removePin:_annotation];
        NSLog(@"The singleton array count is: %u", [Data singleton].annotations.count);
        _vc = [[P2OViewController alloc]init];
        [[self navigationController]pushViewController:_vc
                                          animated:YES];
    }
}
```

My problem is that once the picture is taken, it does not show up in the imageView.

Comment: stupid question, but it has to be made: is your `IBOutlet` `imageView` connected?

Comment: In OSX, after updating a view we need to call the display method of the [View object](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/display). See if there is something similar in iOS too.